# Strip filesize from rclone file list

Tags: text-processing, rclone

I use `rclone` and I want to have the file list without the size of the files mention. I can't find how to do this in `rclone` so I thought of stripping it with awk or something like that. My output looks like this

```
 59183070 fileserver/transfer_kimberly_2022-12-18_0558 (1).zip
     3690 fileserver/transfer_kimberly_2022-12-18_0558 (1).zip - Shortcut.lnk
 35961190 fileserver/transfer_2023-06-27_0814.zip
  7803667 fileserver/woodproject.zip
7437905920 Them/Data/Before_20230526132130642.FDB
1064525824 Them/Data/Updating_20220705231152059.FDB
1064525824 Them backup/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
1064525824 Them backup/Data/Updating_20220705231152059.FDB
1064525824 Them backup/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
  7004362 test.zip
  7004362 test (1).zip
  7803667 37939 37/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
  7803667 37939/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
```

The first number left is the filesize. I want this output

```
fileserver/transfer_kimberly_2022-12-18_0558 (1).zip
fileserver/transfer_kimberly_2022-12-18_0558 (1).zip - Shortcut.lnk
fileserver/transfer_2023-06-27_0814.zip
fileserver/woodproject.zip
Them/Data/Before_20230526132130642.FDB
Them/Data/Updating_20220705231152059.FDB
Them backup/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
Them backup/Data/Updating_20220705231152059.FDB
Them backup/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
test.zip
test (1).zip
37939 37/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
37939/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
```

I thought about stripping everything left of the last `space` that comes before the first `/`. But the `space` in the first directory or file names makes it complicated. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your data is line based. Furthermore it looks like the pattern is "*zero or more spaces, one or more digits, one space*". One tool to edit lines like this is `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]//'
```

I've used character classes (`[[...]]`) but you could also use literal character ranges:

```
sed -E 's/^ *[0-9]+ //'
```

You can use `sed` in a pipe or have it process a file:

```
cmd_a | sed... | cmd_b
sed... {file}
```

Comment: Why not just `sed -E 's/  *[0-9]+  *//'`? Seems like we can safely assume the whitespace is space, and I don't know any reason to use cumbersome and longer format POSIX classes here. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think everyone necessarily uses mechanical copy and paste, but sometimes instead they copy type. When I started writing it (on my phone) I was thinking _space space*_ rather than _space+_ and I wanted something unambiguous

Answer (score 3):

You may use the `lsf` sub-command of `rclone` to list files and directories without listing their file sizes.  Since `lsf` does not recurse by default, you may want to use `lsf -R` if you need to list directories recursively.

If you want only the paths of the *files* (no directories), use `lsf -R —-files-only`. You may also tweak the output format using `--format`, and several options exist for more advanced data filtering (see `rclone lsf —-help`).

---

For easy parsing by further downstream utilities, I would suggest using the JSON output of the `rclone` sub-command `lsjson`.

If using `lsjson` rather than `ls` or `lsf`, then use `jq` (a well-known JSON processing tool) to pull out the `Path` data from each element of the returned JSON array:

```bash
rclone lsjson -R someremote:somepath | jq -r '.[].Path'
```

Note that `lsjson` does not recurse by default, so I use it with its `-R` option here.

If you want to avoid listing directories, then select only array entries whose `IsDir` entry is `false`:

```bash
rclone lsjson -R someremote:somepath | jq -r 'map(select(.IsDir|not))[].Path'
```

(... or use `lsjson -R --files-only`, as with `lsf`.)

---

For reference, `lsjson` will return a JSON array of objects that look like the equivalent of this example (using your data as a mock-up):

```json
{
  "Path": "Them/Data/Before_20230526132130642.FDB",
  "Name": "Before_20230526132130642.FDB",
  "Size": 7437905920,
  "MimeType": "application/octet-stream",
  "ModTime": "2023-09-04T20:10:54.367101898+02:00",
  "IsDir": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Perl**

```perl
~$ perl -pe 's/^\s*\d+\s//;'  file
```

---

**Using Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/^ \s* \d+ \s //;'  file
```

Above are answers written in Perl and Raku. The Perl/Raku `-pe` flags denote execution linewise with autoprinting (`-e` for code alone, `-p` for linewise-autoprinting, i.e. the code gets applied to each line of input and no explicit `print` or `put` is necessary). Note in Raku `\d` includes both ASCII-plus-Unicode digits. If you want ASCII-only in Raku use `<+[0..9]>`.

---

Sample Input:

```
59183070 fileserver/transfer_kimberly_2022-12-18_0558 (1).zip
     3690 fileserver/transfer_kimberly_2022-12-18_0558 (1).zip - Shortcut.lnk
 35961190 fileserver/transfer_2023-06-27_0814.zip
  7803667 fileserver/woodproject.zip
7437905920 Them/Data/Before_20230526132130642.FDB
1064525824 Them/Data/Updating_20220705231152059.FDB
1064525824 Them backup/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
1064525824 Them backup/Data/Updating_20220705231152059.FDB
1064525824 Them backup/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
  7004362 test.zip
  7004362 test (1).zip
  7803667 37939 37/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
  7803667 37939/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
```

Sample Output:

```
fileserver/transfer_kimberly_2022-12-18_0558 (1).zip
fileserver/transfer_kimberly_2022-12-18_0558 (1).zip - Shortcut.lnk
fileserver/transfer_2023-06-27_0814.zip
fileserver/woodproject.zip
Them/Data/Before_20230526132130642.FDB
Them/Data/Updating_20220705231152059.FDB
Them backup/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
Them backup/Data/Updating_20220705231152059.FDB
Them backup/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
test.zip
test (1).zip
37939 37/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
37939/Data/Updating_20220706231124156.FDB
```

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes